# How to send Emails through AWS SNS that has a custom FROM address for every message

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-sns

I am trying to send emails through AWS SNS topic.  However, this is always the `AWS Notifications <no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com>` From email address for all the emails.
I want to customize this and send a different FROM email address every time. Is it possible wiith AWS SNS ?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger a lambda function by SNS and use `boto3` or any other aws-sdk. Build a code to send an email by SES (Simple Email Service) with specific from address. This [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-python.html) will be useful.

Simply, you can do the following.

```
import boto3

ses = boto3.client('ses')

response = ses.send_email(
    Destination={
        'ToAddresses': ['to@domain.com'],
    },
    Message={
        'Body': {
            'Text': {
                'Charset': 'UTF-8',
                'Data': 'email body string',
            },
        },
        'Subject': {
            'Charset': 'UTF-8',
            'Data': 'email subject string',
        },
    },
    Source='from@domain.com',
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, SES is not whitelisted by my company to use currently. So I am trying to see if there is an option through using only SNS. Thanks for the help.

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a way.